# Which of the two points which the function is differentiable

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

$f(x+iy) = 2x + x^2y + i (7x^2/2 + 7y^2/2 -5y)$
Determine the two points where this function is differentiable. What is the real and imaginary part?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you say when a general complex function is differentiable, or what one criterion might be?

Comment: I have done the differentiate what i get is 7xi(7x^2/2+7y^2/2-5y)+2xy+2.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** check Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: I use Cauchy Riemann equation, however i got this equation 2+2xy+ i(7x+7y^2/2-5y) How can I get the real and imaginary part?